# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: macos, syntax, terminal, passwords

I'm trying to test the supposed flaw in OS X Lion, of how unprotected the password is, on my own computer (from [this](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-mac-os-x-lion-passwords-0130036) article). But when I enter the code the in terminal that is supposed to extract the password hash:

```
$ dscl localhost -read /Search/Users/<root user>
```

I get this:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Try: `$ dscl localhost -read "/Search/Users/<root user>" ` it will help if there is empty space between names. And as @nnenneo says you cant use <> in this sample, replace `<root user>` it with your username.

Answer (score 8):

When you see `<xxx>` in a command-line command, it typically means "substitute something here". For example,

```
$ ls <file>
```

doesn't mean to literally type in `ls <file>` in your Terminal, but to type in `ls` followed by some filename.

In this case, they want you to substitute the name of your root user for `<root user>`. For most machines, that is simply `root`.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure bash shell in case your scenarios is this:

$ az webapp stop \

> ```
> --resource-group learn-f69ca399-f99b-4950-84a6-bda8206c6ba0 \
> --name <apiyoachola>
> ```

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

This should solve it

$ az webapp stop \

> ```
> --resource-group learn-f69ca399-f99b-4950-84a6-bda8206c6ba0 \
> --name apiyoachola
> ```